# Wait until QWidget closes

Tags: c++, qt

I'm working on a project in C++ and QT, and I want to open a new QWidget window, have the user interact with it, etc, then have execution return to the method that opened the window. Example (MyClass inherits QWidiget):

```
void doStuff(){

     MyClass newWindow = new Myclass();
     /* 
        I don't want the code down here to 
        execute until newWindow has been closed
      */
}
```

I feel like there is most likely a really easy way to do this, but for some reason I can't figure it out. How can I do this?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Have `MyClass` inherit `QDialog`.  Then open it as a modal dialog with `exec()`.

```
void MainWindow::createMyDialog()
{
  MyClass dialog(this);
  dialog.exec();
}
```

Check out http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdialog.html

Comment: Using a QDialog has side effects - it's rendered differently by default, and the Escape key closes it. I believe @56ka's answer avoid this.

Comment: In case anyone else is tempted to use `setModal()` and `show()`, here's what http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#modal-dialogs says: *"The most common way to display a modal dialog is to call its exec() function. (...) An alternative is to call setModal(true) or setWindowModality(), then show(). Unlike exec(), show() returns control to the caller immediately."*

Comment: Qt5 docs say `QDialog::exec()` is to be avoided. So this answer is no longer best practice (if it ever was).

Answer (score 15):

An other way is to use a loop which waits on the closing event :

```
#include <QEventLoop>

void doStuff()
{
    // Creating an instance of myClass
    MyClass myInstance;
    // (optional) myInstance.setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);  
    myInstance.show();

    // This loop will wait for the window is destroyed
    QEventLoop loop;
    connect(this, SIGNAL(destroyed()), & loop, SLOT(quit()));
    loop.exec();
}
```

Comment: You'll need to connect(&myInstance, SIGNAL(destroyed()), & loop, SLOT(quit())); instead of connect(this, ...) - otherwise you're waiting for your current dialog to be destroyed instead of the myInstance Dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Why not put the code you don't want to be executed till the window has closed in a separate function and connect this as a `SLOT` for the window's close `SIGNAL`?

Comment: Thanks, that sounds like a good idea. How would I do this? I've never hard-coded signals/slots, only used them through QTDesigner.