# wait for event loop to be empty / wait until Qt5 widget is closed

Tags: c++, qt, event-loop

Under Qt5, how to wait until the main event loop has executed all slots that are connected to a specific widget?

Specifically, in the following example

```
class MyWidget : public QWidget {
    ~MyWidget() {
        action_A();
    }
    void myclose() {
        ...
        close();
    }
};

...
auto* w = new MyWidget;
...
w->close();
action_B();
...
```

I want the two functions

```
action_A();
action_B();
```

to be executed in the above order. However, without further precaution, they are executed in the reverse order.

`QWidget::close()` emits a signal which ultimately triggers deletion of the `MyWidget` instance. However, to the best of my understanding, this will only happen after control has returned to the main event loop. In any case, it will not happen before we call `action_B()`.

**Related discussions that don't help:**

- [Wait until QWidget closes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815380), specific for a `QDialog`, accepted answer advises to use `QDialog::exec()`. However, the Qt5 docs recommend to avoid `QDialog::exec()` in favor of `QDialog::open()`. For this and for other reasons I cannot avoid the call to `QDialog::close()`.
- [PyQt: Wait until widget closes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19462112), also depends on `QDialog::exec()`.
- [Does QThread::quit() discard all events in EventQueue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13684700), promoted by @Marek R, involves QThread multithreading, and is too complicated to be of help here

Comment: If you have single-threaded application and don't explicitly use queued connection type, signals are delivered immediately, IOW they are like method calls to all connected slots.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does QThread::quit() discard all events in EventQueue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13684700/does-qthreadquit-discard-all-events-in-eventqueue)

Comment: If you want something to run when a widget is closed, you should catch relevant events on that widget. Once you have instantiated `MyWidget` and set its properties, you should not do anything else: you must return control to the main event loop. Then if something else should be triggered by the closing: do trigger it by the closing.

Comment: @hyde Even in multithreaded applications, signals delivered to the same thread are invoked immediately unless the default is overridden.

Comment: So you're wondering how to determine when all signals are delivered and connections destroyed?

Comment: @hyde, @Jon Harper: As mentioned by @Marek R, `QWidget::close()` may involve `deleteLater()`, which delegates execution to the main event loop.

Answer (score 2):

Simply connect `MyWidget`'s `destroyed()` signal to `action_B` (or something that calls it). Since `action_A` is called from `MyWidget`'s destructor, it will be called before the `destroyed()` signal is emitted in `~QObject()`, and thus, `action_B` called.

Note that you cannot control the timing  of the call of `action_A` as long as it from the destructor of `MyWidget`, so deferring the call to `action_B` is your only choice here, i.e. you cannot make `w->close(); action_B();` work.

Comment: This fully answers my question as it stands. However, I do not want to delay just `action_B` but `action_B` and everything that follows. Hence simply connecting `action_B` to `MyWidget::destroyed` is not enough. Rather I'll need to *wait* for `MyWidget::destroyed` before proceeding with `action_B` and what follows.

Comment: @JoachimW Yes, that is the point of connecting it to a slot and delaying invocation of `action_B`. It will not be called until MyWidget'` destructor is finished (along with others in the inheritance hierarchy) and `QObject`'s destructor has begun, emitting the signal. Wrap your `action_B` and what follows in a slot connected to the aforementioned signal, and you are done needing to wait for it.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think `action_A()` and `action_B()` should be called in this order?

Once the destructor is called, `QObject` will no longer receive any new signals (except those emitted during d-tor execution), since it will not exist and all signals and slots will be disconnected.

Since `action_A()` is a called from the destructor and `action_B()` not,  `action_A()` is executed as last.

Note that `close` may (doesn't have to) call `deleteLater` to destroy the window and this thing schedules destruction of object in event loop.

Comment: Cannot make sense of your sentence 1. In your sentence 3, not clear in which sense you use "must".